# how can i access to my li just with a number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

there is an ul and I need to get the specific li inner html.

I have a number variable that provide before.

how can i use that number to get my li inner html.

tnx

Comment: `$('li').eq( 0basedNumber ).html()`

Comment: Is the number the number that corresponds to the amount of `<li>` in your list, or is the number a separate attribute, like an id, or a name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the UL, then access its `children[]` property. It's a NodeList (which is basically like an Array but tailored for holding nodes), so you can just put your number in there and get the corresponding list item.